# What can I do to accept only one image in the image field in the django admin panel

Tags: django

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(("title"), max_length=50,blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(("image"), upload_to=generate_filename, max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the admin panel, images can be added to this section more than once, what I want is to enter an image only once and then remove the add image button. accept only one image How can I do this?

Comment: @Niloct https://github.com/praekelt/django-preferences this is what worked for me even if it was not exactly what I wanted thank you